# Arduino Piezo Knock Sensor Synth

Tags: arduino, sensor, multiplexer, piezoelectricity, synthesizer

I would like to create a synthesizer using 20 separate piezos for the triggers. In other words, each piezo would trigger a separate tone.

At the very least I would like to know if connecting 20 piezos to an arduino is realistic and how to do it.  I know there are only 5 analogue inputs.  Perhaps instead of each piezo triggering a separate tone, each could trigger the next tone in a cycle.  That way perhaps all of the piezos could be connected through only one analogue input.

I'm just not sure if this is possible or not, any advice would be appreciated.

[This tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Tone3) represents what I would like to do, only my idea calls for a larger scale.

Comment: Did you manage to do this? If so, could you please explain how? I really need it for an art project asap, so it'll be appreciated thx. :) e10durak@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is an analog multiplexer/demultiplexer. These allow you to add analog pins to an Arduino or any other microcontrolle. [Check out how they work.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer)

Here are some links for reference:

- [74HC4067 Specific tutorial](http://bildr.org/2011/02/cd74hc4067-arduino/)
- [Arduino page on the 4051](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Learning/4051)

Answer (score 2):

A very practical approach would be to try and convert that low voltage from the Piezo Sensor to a voltage around ~5V so that you can use it as a digital input for the Arduino. This way ***the CPU load will be low***, since you won't be using the ADC to convert the values every time you need to scan the inputs and the best thing is that you would be able to ***use any IO pin.***

Great place to start would be here: http://www.societyofrobots.com/schematics_voltamp.shtml

> Voltage amplifiers have various uses, but are usually used for boosting smaller voltages to larger ones. Suppose you have a ***sensor that has a voltage range of 10mv to 50mv***. Few microcontrollers can measure this tiny amount! So what you would need to do is amplify this range to say 1V to 5V (since digital logic is usually 5V) 
>   I would like to stress that voltage amplifiers are for amplifying low current/voltage signals (such as from ***force and torque sensors***), not powering things like motors.
>   [http://www.societyofrobots.com/schematics_voltamp.shtml]

Have fun with your project, it sounds really nice :)
Dan